# JAWS Screen reader - use of javascript confirmation dialog

Tags: javascript, dialog, jaws-screen-reader

We have a site which pops a javascript confirmation dialog when the user session is about to timeout, giving the user the option to extend their session or log out.
We are now trying to get this working with JAWS.  On pages which are long ie. it takes JAWS longer than the timeout limit to read it, we are finding that JAWS just keeps reading and won't be interrupted by this dialog.

Is there a way to capture JAWS' attention with this dialog?  It's existing code so we're trying to avoid sweeping changes.  Thanks.

Comment: you're talking about firefox right? you can always warn everyone a min sooner...

Comment: Sorry, no - IE11 specifically.  And once the pop-up is 'popped-up' they user has 1 minute to press a button.  Trouble is that we have a couple of very long pages (Terms & Conditions etc) which take ages (timeout limit plus 3 mins or so).

Comment: ahh, i see. in that case, you're going to want to breakup the content into smaller chunks to allow AT to drill into bite-sized pieces. this is important because if you interrupt a 5-min read-out and the user can't easily resume where they were, it's a real bummer to those who want to consume the end of that long text. think of how frustrating online videos are when you can't jump around...

Comment: For sure - that makes good sense.  But we're breaking it up using <p> but it still won't acknowledge the pop-up.  It's as if it caches the entire page then takes a deep breath and goes for it.  Is there another way we should try breaking it up?

Comment: well you can make it shut up by focus()ing something else just before you call confirm(), but then how do they get back? Un-intuitively, UL/LIs are pretty good for long stretches of content (there's a list mode in most AT), and a little CSS can make them look like P tags (list-style:none;display:block;etc). even simple anchored headers in each P and a sub-page navigation section allow the user to resume to a mid-point of a long passage, somewhat like DVD chapters allow after an accidental eject...